# Problems Creating CSV from Python with Array of Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, csv

So I have a python that collects data points from various DAQ units and all I want to do is spit them out into a CSV.  I had the code working perfectly with my sample arrays, but I can't get this working for the life of me now.

So here's what I've got:

```
with open(FileName, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = ',')
    writer.writerow(Header)
    i = 0
    TotalRuns = NumTestCycles
    while i < TotalRuns:
        ExportLine = RecordedData[i]
        writer.writerow(ExportLine)
        i = i + 1
```

Now, this code produces the "iterable" error for writer.writerow(ExportLine).

So then I wrap the ExportLine in [] and it produces my CSV, but each line shows up as

```
[232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237]
```

in each cell rather than a single number per cell.

My array is set up as

```
RecordedData = [[232,233,234,235,236,237],[232,233,234,235,236,237]]
```

All I want is my excel sheet to look like:

```
Title 1 | Title 2 | Title 3 | Title 4 | Title 5 | Title 6
----------------------------------------------------------
  232   |   233   |   234   |   235   |   236   |   237
----------------------------------------------------------
  232   |   233   |   234   |   235   |   236   |   237
```

What am I missing here?  Why will it spit the line out properly with my array of strings but not my array of numbers?

I've tried the for loop method and it just produces one massive row with a sub-array in each cell.  I tried writer.writerows(RecordedData) and it only produces the very last data point... as an array in one cell...

I'm beating my head against a wall here.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I wrap the ExportLine in `[]`"? Can you show us that code?

Comment: blhsing, sorry.  By the time I wrote this up my eyes were dry and red and I had been tunnel vision on the screen for over 6 hours straight.  I wasn't thinking very clearly.  here's what I mean by that:

Comment: while i < TotalRuns:
        ExportLine = RecordedData[i]
        writer.writerow([ExportLine])
        i = i + 1

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

Note adding `newline=''` in the `open` block stops blank lines from being added between each row in the file.

```
import csv

RecordedData = [[232,233,234,235,236,237],[232,233,234,235,236,237]]
Header = 'Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4', 'Title 5', 'Title 6' 
with open('test.csv', "w", newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        i = 0
        writer.writerow(Header)
        TotalRuns = 1  #Changed to assumed NumTestCycles value from example data give
        while i <= TotalRuns:
            ExportLine = RecordedData[i]
            writer.writerow(ExportLine)
            i += 1
```

Output from Excel:

```
   A    |    B    |    C    |    D    |    E    |    F
----------------------------------------------------------
Title 1 | Title 2 | Title 3 | Title 4 | Title 5 | Title 6
----------------------------------------------------------
  232   |   233   |   234   |   235   |   236   |   237
----------------------------------------------------------
  232   |   233   |   234   |   235   |   236   |   237
```

*Edited to include your Header line

*Edit 2, you can also try using `.writerows()` in leu of iterating through your list, this should solve your error.

```
import csv

RecordedData = [[232,233,234,235,236,237],[232,233,234,235,236,237]]
Header = 'Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4', 'Title 5', 'Title 6' 
with open('test.csv', "w", newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(Header)
    TotalRuns = 1  #Changed to assumed NumTestCycles value from example data give
    writer.writerows(RecordedData)
```

Comment: Pete, so if I run that as shown I get the "iterable expected, not int" error. So then I just do the "writer.writerow([ExportLine])" change and..... same thing.  I get nice rows, but each row is one cell with the entire array saved to ExportLine in that one cell wrapped in [] (exactly what I showed earlier). Now, for kicks I tried converting the array to str and the result was very interesting. It took every number (decimals, 10s place, 100s place, 10th place, 100th place) and put them in their own cell.  It was like a character per cell. Not gonna work, but interesting.

Comment: Pete, I gotta be missing something fundamental.  When I punch in the edit#2 I still get Error: iterable expected, not int

Comment: @InjuNear are you putting the code in your project? or running it standalone to see if it works on your system?

Comment: Putting it in the project,  I'll go run it alone and report back.

Comment: I am going to go find a good tall bridge to jump off... JK... sort of.  So I ran your code isolated in a test program and it worked perfectly.  so I thought "WTF?".  So I commented out my code, which was verbatim your code, copy pasted yours in just for kicks, ran it and....... perfect.  First try.  I don't know why I suck, but I love you for saving me on this.  THANK YOU!

Comment: I stand corrected.  Now I know what's going on sort of.  It works perfectly as long as my DAQ isn't connected.  As soon as I hook up my DAQ it goes back to the iterable error.  How could that be?  I'm using a manufacturer provided python code for the DAQ driver.  That's so dumb that it works without numbers coming from the DAQ but croaks when the values are non-zero.

Comment: @InjuNear can you edit your question and add the code that receives data from the DAQ, has to be a format issue somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.  The code Pete shows above (with writerows) is perfect.  It solves the funky issue of putting the entire array in one cell.  The reason it was giving the iterable error had nothing to do with the code.  In fact, I kind of suspect the arrays in each cell might not have been the code either, but I'm far to lazy to go back and check that since it's working now.  The issue was timing.

I have the DAQ recording proceedure wrapped up in a while loop based on a timer.  The user enters a total time for the test and a time interval at which they want to take measurements.  The loop runs through with the total time as its perameter and at the beginning of each loop it checks the elapse time and if it's within range of the interval it records the data from the DAQ(s) into the array.

The whole process of recording the DAQ data takes some time apparently.  If the user enters an interval of less that 3 seconds (I did some testing) the program will enter into DAQ recording on one cycle and by the time it comes out it missed the window for the next recording so it skips it.  Basically it winds up recording every other cycle (or less).

This is a problem because I had to initialize my array using

```
RecordedData = [0 for i in range(1, NumTestCycles)]
```

That means I have an array full of zeros to begin with.  Since the timing issue caused it to record on every other cycle, half of the array was still zeros when it got to the CSV export.  The CSV pulls the arrays of that array just fine, but then it gets to the zeros and pops the "iterable expected, not int" error because it was expecting an array and got a zero.

I discovered this by accident, but I now know that if I run the interval as 4 seconds or more there are no errors and I get a perfect file.

Thank you for all your help on this!